# PHP laravel query

Tags: php, database, laravel

How can I query all users whose last donation is more than 90 days.  This is my query but when it is executed I get an error unknown column.

```
      $value = Session::get('key');
      $dateToday = new DateTime();
      $data = Users::where('userType','=', 'user' )
                ->where($dateToday->format('m/d/Y') - 'lastDonation', '=', 1)
                ->whereNotIn('username', [$value ])
                ->get();
```

Comment: To save your time, you could check your code by using `dd($data->toSql())` and remove `->get()` to re-check your query builder

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = Users::where('userType','=', 'user' )
->where('lastDonation', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(90))
->whereNotIn('username', [$value ])
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) mysql function to compute the difference between two datetimes.

To do that you need to add a clause using `whereRaw`

```
$value = Session::get('key');
$dateToday = new DateTime();
$data = Users::where('userType', '=', 'user')
          ->whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, lastDonation, NOW()) > 90')
          ->whereNotIn('username', [$value])
          ->get();
```